# Не работате npm i на mac

Tags: node.js, vagrant, homestead

при npm i выдает, использую Homestead vagrant на Mac

```
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   linux
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-06-16T13_09_31_044Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Любопытно, он у Вас почему-то считает, что вы запускаете его не под MacOS, а под Линуксом.

Comment: разобрался, я запускал под вагрантом, запустил под os  и все заработало